# Avoid duplicate columns select on nested select

Tags: sql, cratedb

In CrateDB is there a way to avoid to re-select the same column in nested `SELECT` statement, to show the value in the results?

e.i. in the following query, is there any way to avoid re-selecting A and B through the nested `SELECT`? Ideally would be nice to select just once in the first

```
SELECT
A,
B,
AB,
A * B * AB  AS ABAB,
A / AB::DECIMAL AS AAB,
FROM (
    SELECT
        A,
        B,
        (A + B) AS AB,
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            (SELECT count(*) FROM schema.table_01 WHERE process_state IN ('State_1')) AS A,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM schema.table_01 WHERE process_state IN ('State_2')) AS B,
    ) alias_for_subquery_01
) alias_for_subquery_02
```

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you could use `*` in your derived table if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, I was so foolish not to think about it! :D